# (Getting an exception while fetching data from JSON) type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'

Tags: android, json, flutter

We are facing this exception while fetching data from the JSON and we have attached the code as well as the JSON format.

Not sure on reason why I am getting exception " Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f' ". Everything seems to be done correctly but still getting exception

Product File

```
class Product {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? image;
  int? price;
  int? discount;
  String? description;
  Category? category;
  int? finalprice;
  bool? favorites;
  bool? exclusive;
  Product(
      {this.id,
      this.title,
      this.image,
      this.price,
      this.discount,
      this.description,
      this.category,
      this.finalprice,
      this.favorites,
      this.exclusive});

  Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    image = json['image'];
    price = json['price'];
    discount = json['discount'];
    description = json['description'];
    category = json['category'] != null
        ? new Category.fromJson(json['category'])
        : null;
    finalprice = json['finalprice'];
    favorites = json['favorites'];
    exclusive = json['exclusive'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['discount'] = this.discount;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    if (this.category != null) {
      data['category'] = this.category!.toJson();
    }
    data['finalprice'] = this.finalprice;
    data['favorites'] = this.favorites;
    data['exclusive'] = this.exclusive;
    return data;
  }
}

class Category {
  int? id;
  String? categoryName;

  Category({this.id, this.categoryName});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    categoryName = json['category'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['category_name'] = this.categoryName;
    return data;
  }
}
```

ProductDataStructure.dart file

```
class ProductDataStacture with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Product> _products = [];



Future<bool> getProducts() async {
    String url = 'https://ecom.techoxy.in';

try {
  http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url + "/home"),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'token a867c3c092e8b1195f398ed5ca52dda4e5ff5ed8'
      });
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  print(data);
  List<Product> demo = [];
  data.forEach((element) {
    Product product = Product.fromJson(element);
    demo.add(product);
    print(product);
  });
  _products = demo;
  return true;
} catch (e) {
  print("e getProducts");
  print(e);
  return true;
}


 }



List<Product> get productsList {
    return [..._products];
  }

}
```

JSON format

```
{
    "banners": [
        {
            "name": "Test Banner",
            "image": "/media/banners/Diwali-image-1200x600.jpg",
            "link": "#",
            "first": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Test2",
            "image": "/media/banners/Flipkart-Big-Diwali-Sale-2020.jpg",
            "link": "#",
            "first": true
        }
    ],
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Plain White Shirt",
            "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mens-shirt-picture-id488160041?k=20&m=488160041&s=612x612&w=0&h=OH_-skyES8-aeTvDQHdVDZ6GKLsqp6adFJC8u6O6_UY=",
            "description": "xcvipoer erefc",
            "price": 2013.54,
            "discount": 0.0,
            "finalprice": 2013.54,
            "exclusive": true,
            "favourites": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "username": "billa",
                    "photo": null
                }
            ],
            "cart": [],
            "category": {
                "name": "Shirts",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Clothing",
                    "image": null
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "categories": [
        {
            "name": "Clothing",
            "image": null
        }
    ],
    "primary": [
        {
            "name": "Test Banner",
            "image": "/media/banners/Diwali-image-1200x600.jpg",
            "link": "#",
            "first": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Test3",
            "image": "/media/banners/Diwali-image-1200x600_nJrJRij.jpg",
            "link": "#",
            "first": false
        }
    ],
    "secondary": [
        {
            "name": "Test Banner",
            "image": "/media/banners/Diwali-image-1200x600.jpg",
            "link": "#",
            "first": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Test3",
            "image": "/media/banners/Diwali-image-1200x600_nJrJRij.jpg",
            "link": "#",
            "first": false
        }
    ],
    "dailydeal": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Plain White Shirt",
            "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mens-shirt-picture-id488160041?k=20&m=488160041&s=612x612&w=0&h=OH_-skyES8-aeTvDQHdVDZ6GKLsqp6adFJC8u6O6_UY=",
            "description": "xcvipoer erefc",
            "price": 2013.54,
            "discount": 0.0,
            "finalprice": 2013.54,
            "exclusive": true,
            "favourites": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "username": "billa",
                    "photo": null
                }
            ],
            "cart": [],
            "category": {
                "name": "Shirts",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Clothing",
                    "image": null
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "random": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "shirt",
            "image": "https://minimal-kit-react.vercel.app/static/mock-images/products/product_7.jpg",
            "description": "dfmkdgfdkmgnfdgn",
            "price": 521463.02,
            "discount": 0.0,
            "finalprice": 521463.02,
            "exclusive": false,
            "favourites": [],
            "cart": [],
            "category": {
                "name": "Footwear",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Clothing",
                    "image": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "tshirt",
            "image": "https://minimal-kit-react.vercel.app/static/mock-images/products/product_2.jpg",
            "description": "fdg aodkrorf sedfmsdkg",
            "price": 6589.46,
            "discount": 0.0,
            "finalprice": 6589.46,
            "exclusive": false,
            "favourites": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "username": "billa",
                    "photo": null
                }
            ],
            "cart": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "total": 13178.92,
                    "active": false,
                    "user": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$260000$GUUdFMt9N0G2itKiCNPCu1$05cKKGxS969qAIvxbziYsQl/f9uMk0Vqd9FXeUBRs6A=",
                        "username": "billa",
                        "email": "billa@gmail.com",
                        "name": null,
                        "date_joined": "2021-11-15T14:43:11.457711Z",
                        "last_login": "2021-11-24T16:29:33.919578Z",
                        "is_staff": true,
                        "is_superuser": true,
                        "type": "S",
                        "photo": null,
                        "contact": null,
                        "address": [
                            1,
                            2
                        ]
                    },
                    "product": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "title": "tshirt",
                        "poster": null,
                        "image": "https://minimal-kit-react.vercel.app/static/mock-images/products/product_2.jpg",
                        "size": null,
                        "description": "fdg aodkrorf sedfmsdkg",
                        "quantity": null,
                        "quantityunit": null,
                        "stockuntil": null,
                        "price": 6589.46,
                        "discount": 0.0,
                        "gst": 0.0,
                        "taxamount": 0.0,
                        "finalprice": 6589.46,
                        "averagerating": 3.2,
                        "added": "2021-11-15T14:46:26.137948Z",
                        "edited": "2021-11-17T08:04:57.949012Z",
                        "exclusive": false,
                        "dailydeal": false,
                        "category": 1,
                        "favourites": [
                            1
                        ],
                        "cart": [
                            7
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "category": {
                "name": "Footwear",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Clothing",
                    "image": null
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Plain White Shirt",
            "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/mens-shirt-picture-id488160041?k=20&m=488160041&s=612x612&w=0&h=OH_-skyES8-aeTvDQHdVDZ6GKLsqp6adFJC8u6O6_UY=",
            "description": "xcvipoer erefc",
            "price": 2013.54,
            "discount": 0.0,
            "finalprice": 2013.54,
            "exclusive": true,
            "favourites": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "username": "billa",
                    "photo": null
                }
            ],
            "cart": [],
            "category": {
                "name": "Shirts",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Clothing",
                    "image": null
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Updated Code: This is the updated code

```
try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url + "/home"),
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'token a867c3c092e8b1195f398ed5ca52dda4e5ff5ed8'
          });
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      print(data);
      List<Product> demo = [];
      data['products'].forEach((element) {
        Product product = Product.fromJson(element);
        demo.add(product);
        print(product);
      });
      _products = demo;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("e getProducts");
      print(e);
      return true;
    }
```

Console output:

```
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone x86 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:55482/rQGykIbE6KQ=/
I/flutter ( 8707): e getProducts
I/flutter ( 8707): SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'ecom.techoxy.in' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

Comment: in which line you are getting this error ??

Comment: It is generating the exception from product data structure file in catch block. I am new to this if possible kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: The SocketException you're getting is related to network issues. Check if you can still call the API manually (through an http client tool like curl, postman, etc...) and that the device you're running this on has connection to the internet

Comment: Now its giving this

"type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Category?'"

Answer (score 0):

Your json response is an object, not an array. Parsing it to Product objects with `data.forEach((element) ...` will not work. Maybe you only want to parse `data['products']` here instead?

If that's the case, you can use `data['products'].forEach(...)` and it will no longer give that error, but you have some other things that aren't correct.

- The values for `price`, `discount` and `finalprice` should be `double` instead of `int`.
- `favorites` is a list of some sort of object, but is defined as a `bool`
- the category name has 3 different keys for `toJson`, `fromJson` and in the actual json

Comment: I have added the updated code but its throwing the exception, I have added an edit to my question